# Is there a way to ingest data through IOT HUB into ADX(Azure Data Explorer) and assign tags

Tags: azure, schema, kql, azure-data-explorer

I have a setup where i have multiple devices connected to and ADX cluster database. Each device is senting telemetry data to the iot hub and then it ingests into the database. There is a single device that also sends data to the database but I dont want to process its data into the child tables and keeping a saperate column in the database will be redundent as the single device sends data scarsly. I have serched about extend_tags() and it seems like my desired solution.

I have tried to add tags in json mapping using with(tags="['ignore']") but it did nothing

Comment: please share the data format you are sending and How you are sending to Azure Iot hub .please in the question

Comment: What is `extend_tags()`, ? Which programming language or tool are you using? Could you explain the requirement in detail?

Comment: @Sampath I am sending data in Json format

Comment: @Aswin I am taking about KQL which is the native language used in Azure data explorer

Comment: @Aswin
this is the way to connect IOT hub to data explorer. However, I am sending data from multiple sources, of which I want to run my update policy on all the rows except sent by a particular device without adding any additional columns to the tables

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to ingest data through IoT Hub into ADX (Azure Data Explorer):**

**Create an IoT Hub data connection:**

- Navigate to your Azure Data Explorer cluster in the Azure portal.
- Select "Databases" from the left menu and choose the database containing your target table.
- Click on "Data connections" and then "Add data connection."
- Choose "IoT Hub" from the dropdown menu.
- Select the Azure Data Explorer cluster and database. Create a cluster and [database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/create-event-hubs-connection?tabs=get-data%2Cget-data-2).

[image]

- Create a table in ADX to store the ingested data using Azure Data Explorer Dashboards for IoT [Data](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/internet-of-things-blog/azure-data-explorer-dashboards-for-iot-data/ba-p/2095138).
- Establish an IoT Hub data connection with Azure Data [Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/create-iot-hub-connection?tabs=portal).

[image]

[image]

- Ingest from IoT Hub using Azure Data [Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-iot-hub-overview)

[image]

Comment: this is the way to connect IOT hub to data explorer. However, I am sending data from multiple sources, of which I want to run my update policy on all the rows except sent by a particular device without adding any additional columns to the tables

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/update-policy) to update the policy on all the rows